# How to transfer a environment variable into a dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

How can I transfer a environment variable into the dockerfile?

The variable is dynamic, so I can not use ENV to do that.

like `$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )` is the way to tell where a bash script locate. How can a Dockerfile tell which path it locate?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ENV` directive, for example `ENV abc 123` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/  extract

The ENV instruction sets the environment variable  to the value . This value will be in the environment of all “descendent” Dockerfile commands and can be replaced inline in many as well.

The ENV instruction has two forms. The first form, ENV  , will set a single variable to a value

So I do not think we can guess the directory

> > > Can a dockerfile tell what directory it's stored in?

usually you create a specific directory, create your Dockerfile inside, put the files needed (that your will copy either with `ADD` or `COPY`) and launch `docker build .` (and with recent versions of docker like 1.5, you can specify the location of the Dockerfile you use

extract from the doc
http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/build/

`-f, --file=""            Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')`

> > > Can a dockerfile tell what directory it's stored in?

Unless you use some tricks, I do not think. What is the point?